# Binary tree with higher numbers higher in the tree

Tags: javascript, data-structures, binary-tree

I want to generate a tree of users, with users of higher scores towards the top of the tree. I can create a binary search tree, however, the distribution of the users is left to right, not top to bottom. eg.

left to right distribution binary search tree

```
          4
      /        \
     2          6
   /   \       / \
  1     3     5   7
```

Top to bottom distribution, with the highest score highest in the tree

```
          7
      /        \
     5          6
   /   \       / \
  1     2     3   4
```

Users will be independent, they will be able to disconnect from the tree, or can be shuffled when their scores change or users with different scores are introduced to the system.

Performance and efficiency is not important, only hierarchy with a clear dependency tree, although as few changes as possible to the structure is desired.

This seemed like a simple problem when I conceived the idea, however, the implementation seems more complicated the more I try.

I never went to University so don't have the grounding in data structures, anything you can do to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

```js
class Node {
  left: null
  right: null
  constructor(id, score) {
    this.id = id
    this.score = score
  }
}

class Tree {
  root: null
  constructor(root) {
    this.root = root
  }
}

const addNode = (tree, node) => {
  const go = (parent) => {
    if (node.score <= parent.score) {
      if (!parent.left) {
        parent.left = node;
      } else {
        go(parent.left);
      }
    } else {
      if (!parent.right) {
        parent.right = node;
      } else {
        go(parent.right);
      }
    }
  };
  go(tree.root);
}

const tree = new Tree(new Node(1, 7))
addNode(tree, new Node(2, 6))
addNode(tree, new Node(3, 5))
addNode(tree, new Node(4, 4))
addNode(tree, new Node(5, 3))
addNode(tree, new Node(6, 2))
addNode(tree, new Node(7, 1))

console.log(tree)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: You are looking, I believe for a [max-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))

Comment: That looks promising, thanks for your help